# Hexproof and Aether Storm

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I'm setting up to build a [Zur, Eternal Schemer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zur%2C%20Eternal%20Schemer) deck and I came across [Aether Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aether%20Storm). Now, I could be reading this wrong, and it's unlikely to actually happen, but Zur gives enchantment creatures hexproof and some other stuff, and can turn Enchantments into Enchantment Creatures. Aether Storm is powerful but can normally be cancelled out by the fact anyone can get rid of it. But since this is treated as an ability (stated in the updated text) and hexproof prevents targeting by abilities and spells, would giving it hexproof cover that clause?

Comment: Pithing Needle can do what you want, as well Karn's Sylex and similar cards.

Answer (score 9):

**No, Aether Storm's second ability is not affected by hexproof.**

Hexproof only prevents abilities from *targeting* permanents. But, Aether Storm's ability (like most abilities that affect only the card they're printed on) doesn't have a target.

> 115.10a Just because an object or player is being affected by a spell or ability doesn’t make that object or player a target of that spell or ability. Unless that object or player is identified by the word “target” in the text of that spell or ability, or the rule for that keyword ability, it’s not a target.

Aether Storm's ability doesn't have the word "target", so it doesn't target anything.

> Pay 4 life: Destroy Aether Storm. It can't be regenerated. Any player may activate this ability.